# setValue forKey in NSMutableDictionary crashes

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutabledictionary

I have the code like below. I am retrieving JSON from a web server.

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
                                     {    

                                         for (NSMutableDictionary * dataDict in JSON) {


                                             if ([dataDict objectForKey:@"userPicture"])
                                             {

                                                objectForKey:@"userPicture"]);
                                                 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[dataDict objectForKey:@"userPicture"]];
                                                 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];     


                                                 [dataDict setValue:@"userPicture"
                                                             forKey:@"userPicture"]; 


                                             } 


                                             [messageList addObject: dataDict];
                                         }                                             

                                         [self processComplete];

                                     } 
                                    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSURLResponse *response , NSError *error , id JSON)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"Failed: %@", error);        

                                     }];
```

However it crashes with the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary
>   setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Now, what I don't get is that, I am trying to `setValue:forKey` in dataDict, which is instantiated `NSMutableDictionary`, so I should be able to setValue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared your dataDict as an NSMutableDictionary but that doesn't mean that you get a mutable dictionary from your JSON. What you could do is either instruct your JSON serializer to fetch you mutable copies (if it supports such option) or manually do this:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in JSON) {

    NSMutableDictionary * dataDict = [dict mutableCopy];
    // Rest of the code here...

}
```

Comment: Remember to release `dataDict`.

Comment: @jrtc27 True. I just wanted to stress out the mutable part (also didn't now if the guy is using ARC).

Comment: He could be using ARC. I often forget about it, as none of my projects use it.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped me a lot. Guess I will have to get a lot more familiar with how pointer and stuff work :) Much appreciated!... And just for the record. I am using ARC. Is there any downside to this?

Comment: No in fact Apple encourages you to do so. Of course it's always a good idea to understand manual memory management but ARC is a brand new technology which will eventually be the standard.

Answer (score 1):

`dataDict` is just a pointer, is not instantiated.

You are actually dealing with simple `NSDictionary`, so you cannot modify it. If you need to modify it just call `mutableCopy` on it. This will make you the owner of the object so, if you are not using ARC, remember to release it when you have done.

Comment: In other words, typecasting an object towards a mutable dictionary does not make it a mutable dictionary.